# Webview javascript not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to put user login after page successfully load,i am using javascript like

```
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"myText\").value = \"Johnny Bravo\";" );
    }
```

but can't seem any changes I already tested javascript working if I using just

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: alert('yes javascript working';" );
    }
```

I am really stucked can't understand what is wrong with android...

Answer (score 0):

What I have tried before is like this :

1. Set that webview already accept javascript(in your case, I believe
   it is already ok)
2. Determining whether the webview already loaded
3. Take a necessary change

> ```
>    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
>        public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {  
>             wv.loadUrl("javascript:addmyindica('"+indicator+"','"+param+"')");
>
>        }
>    });
> ```

Hopefully this can help you

Note: make sure you didn't encounter conflict with another rendering process after onload process.

Best Regards,

Steve